# how to set password for ssh connection in java

Tags: java, ssh

I want to connect my unix server using java code. first it will connect to my server location. inside that it'll connect to my server name. but at that time it'll ask for confirmation (yes/no) and password I don't know how to do?
Here's my code that I have done.please help me out on this

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    String user = "user";
    String password = "password";
    String host = "hostName";
    int port=22;

    //String remoteFile="/home/john/test.txt";
    //String yes="yes";

    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
        session.connect();
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

        // After this it'll ask for confirmation and password
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("ssh myServerName");
        channel.connect();

        InputStream output = channel.getInputStream();

        System.out.println("aafter stream");
        int readByte = output.read();
        StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        while (readByte != 0xffffffff) {
            //System.out.println("read byte" + readByte);
            outputBuffer.append((char)readByte);
            readByte = output.read();
        }
        System.out.println(outputBuffer.toString());
        channel.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.err.print("error message" + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you again connecting to your server once it is already connected?

Comment: Nope I connected to my server location. inside different servers are there. I tried to connect one of them. I tried to connect server direct it has shown "unknown host exception"

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the OutputStream of JSch secured channel and insert the password in it.

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("sudo -S -p '' " + command);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);
        channel.connect();
        out.write((password + "\n").getBytes());
        out.flush();
```

Complete source code here: http://codeflex.co/java-run-sudo-command-on-remote-linux-host/

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
    session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
}
catch (JSchException e) {
    throw new TransferException("Failed to open session - " + params, e);
}

session.setPassword(password);

//  Create UserInfo instance in order to support SFTP connection to any machine 
//  without a key username and password will be given via UserInfo interface.
UserInfo userInfo = new SftpUserInfo();
session.setUserInfo(userInfo);

try {
    session.connect(connectTimeout);
}
catch (JSchException e) {
    throw new TransferException("Failed to connect to session - " + params, e);
}

boolean isSessionConnected = session.isConnected();
```

Set the password programmatically like seen above.

Comment: Can please you elaborate little bit what can be in my SftpUserInfo class?

Comment: because here it is showing there is no class like SftpUserInfo

Comment: one last thing can I have any option that I can give this thing implicitly not with user interaction?

Comment: one more thing where I am giving location for that sftp file? and here it is showing session already connected

Comment: and I think you are not getting my point I have one connection inside that I have to connect to my server